# simple error on datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error in simple entry into a `datetime` column. How to enter this data?

We are using SQL Server 2005 here

Error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Code:

```
 insert into OGEN.EMR_MONITOR_TRANSACTIONS (PATIENT_ID, MONITOR_CODE, RESULTS, RESULTS_VALUES, NOTE, ADD_OBSERVATIONS, DATE_ENTERED, ENTERED_BY)
  Values('103545281', 'P100', '1', '1', ' ', '111', '2014-11-11 05:05:05', 'Nurse1')
```

Defined:

```
DATE_ENTERED datetime
```

I tried this way as well 20141118 10:34:09 AM and also this '12-mar-2013'same error

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Can you share the table definition for `OGEN.EMR_MONITOR_TRANSACTIONS`? The insert statement appears correct, so maybe there's something else contributing to the error.

Comment: @marc_s Please show us your table definition. This query may work fine without error if there is not any design issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

So in your concrete case - try this:

```
INSERT INTO OGEN.EMR_MONITOR_TRANSACTIONS (PATIENT_ID, MONITOR_CODE, RESULTS, RESULTS_VALUES, NOTE, ADD_OBSERVATIONS, DATE_ENTERED, ENTERED_BY)
VALUES('103545281', 'P100', '1', '1', ' ', '111', '20141111T05:05:05', 'Nurse1')
```

Answer (score 0):

`'20141111 05:05:05'` (no 'AM' or 'PM') should convert correctly regardless of language settings.